# Getting a WCF service (both host/client) to work on https on Linux with Mono

Tags: linux, wcf, https, mono

I have a small test console application that serves as the WCF host and another console application that serves as the client.

The client can reach the host via http, everything works fine so far.
But when switching to https, I get the following error:

```
Error: System.Net.WebException: Error: SendFailure (Error writing headers) --->
System.Net.WebException: Error writing headers --->
System.IO.IOException: The authentication or decryption has failed. --->
Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.TlsException: The authentication or decryption has failed.
...
```

The steps so far I have attempted to solve the issue:

- I have verified that the ca-certificates-mono package is installed
- I have imported the CA certs to the machine store with (why do I need this if I work with a selfsigned cert?)

  `sudo mozroots --import --machine --sync`
- I created a selfsigned cert for testing with (as described in the Mono Security FAQ)

  `makecert -r -eku 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1 -n "CN=Cert4SSL" -sv cert.pvk cert.cer`
- I added it to the mono cert store

  `sudo certmgr -add -c -m Trust cert.cer`

  I have also did tests with other stores (Root, My) and also using not the maching but the user's store - none did work, the same error on each attempt
- I assigned port my service uses to the cert

  `httpcfg -add -port 6067 -cert cert.cer -pvk cert.pvk`
- I added ignoring the certificate validation

  `ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (o, certificate, chain, errors) => true;`

  This did not help either (but it got called, the cert object looked allright in the debugger).

The client uses this code to call the WebService:

```
IService svcClient2 = null;
string address2 = "https://localhost:6067/TestService";
BasicHttpBinding httpBinding2 = new BasicHttpBinding();
httpBinding2.TransferMode = TransferMode.Buffered;
httpBinding2.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport;
httpBinding2.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.None;
httpBinding2.MessageEncoding = WSMessageEncoding.Text;
httpBinding2.UseDefaultWebProxy = true;
ChannelFactory<IService> channelFac2 = new ChannelFactory<IService>( httpBinding2, new EndpointAddress( address2 ) );
svcClient2 = channelFac2.CreateChannel();
string res2 = svcClient2.TestHello( "Bob" );   // <----- this is where I get the exception
```

Any help is appreciated, I feel like running in circles.

A few infos about the environment:
I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and Mono 4.0.2, IDE is MonoDevelop

edit: I have now built the very same projects with visual studio and C#, there it works as expected. The client can connect to the host on both http and https.
If i copy over the mono version to my Windows machine, I run into the same issue and error message as on Ubuntu.

Could this be a mono-related issue?